# How to make it run sync?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, c++98

Hello I want to sync two threads one incrementing a variable and other decrementing it.
The result that I want looks like:

`Thread #0 j = 1`

`Thread #1 j = 0`

`Thread #0 j = 1`

`Thread #1 j = 0`

And so on.. but my code sometimes works like that in some cases it print really weird values. I supose that I have some undefined behavior in somewhere but I can't figured out what is really happen.

My code consist in a `HANDLE ghMutex` that containg the handler of my mutex:

My main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE aThread[THREADCOUNT];

    ghMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);             

    aThread[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &inc, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);
    aThread[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &dec, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);

    ResumeThread(aThread[0]);
    ResumeThread(aThread[1]);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADCOUNT, aThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    printf("j = %d\n", j);

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++)
        CloseHandle(aThread[i]);

    CloseHandle(ghMutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Inc function:

```
unsigned int __stdcall inc(LPVOID)
{
    for (volatile int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(
            ghMutex,    // handle to mutex
            INFINITE);  // no time-out interval

            j++;
            printf("Thread %d j = %d\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), j);
            ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);

    }
    _endthread();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Dec function:

```
unsigned int __stdcall dec(void*)
{
    for (volatile int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(
            ghMutex,    // handle to mutex
            INFINITE);  // no time-out interval

        j--;
        printf("Thread %d j = %d\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), j);
        ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);
    }
    _endthread();

    return TRUE;
}
```

I need a win api solution in std c++98.

Comment: you need 2 events(0,1) for this. every thread (i) signal event (1-i) and wait for event(i). say `SignalObjectAndWait` here useful. before win 8.1 was object eventpair - it it was perfect for such a task, but by unknown reason it was removed from windows

Comment: declare local variable as *volatile*, which will be accessed only from single thread - no any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows mutex object guarantees exclusive ownership, but does not care about the ownership order. so that the same thread can capture several times in a row while others will wait.

for your task you need signal to another thread, when your task is done, and then wait for signal from another thread. for this task can be used event pair for example. thread *(i)* signal event *(1-i)* and wait on event *(i)*. for optimize instead 2 calls -

```
SetEvent(e[1-i]); WaitForSingleObject(e[i], INFINITE);
```

we can use single call [`SignalObjectAndWait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-signalobjectandwait)

```
SignalObjectAndWait(e[1-i], e[i], INFINITE, FALSE)
```

of course start and end of loop require special care. for `inc`

```
    HANDLE hObjectToSignal  = _hEvent[1], hObjectToWaitOn  = _hEvent[0];

    for (;;)
    {
        _shared_value++;

        if (!--n)
        {
            SetEvent(hObjectToSignal);
            break;
        }

        SignalObjectAndWait(hObjectToSignal, hObjectToWaitOn, INFINITE, FALSE);
    }
```

and for `dec`

```
    HANDLE hObjectToSignal  = _hEvent[0], hObjectToWaitOn  = _hEvent[1];

    WaitForSingleObject(hObjectToWaitOn, INFINITE);
    for (;;)
    {
        --_shared_value;

        if (!--n)
        {
            break;
        }

        SignalObjectAndWait(hObjectToSignal, hObjectToWaitOn, INFINITE, FALSE);
    }
```

if write full test, with error checking

```
struct Task 
{
    HANDLE _hEvent[4];
    ULONG _n;
    LONG _iTasks;
    LONG _shared_value;

    Task()
    {
        RtlZeroMemory(this, sizeof(*this));
    }

    ~Task()
    {
        ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(_hEvent);
        do 
        {
            if (HANDLE hEvent = _hEvent[--n]) CloseHandle(hEvent);
        } while (n);
    }

    ULONG WaitTaskEnd()
    {
        return WaitForSingleObject(_hEvent[2], INFINITE);
    }

    ULONG WaitTaskReady()
    {
        return WaitForSingleObject(_hEvent[3], INFINITE);
    }

    void SetTaskReady()
    {
        SetEvent(_hEvent[3]);
    }

    void End()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_iTasks)) SetEvent(_hEvent[2]);
    }

    void Begin()
    {
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_iTasks);
    }

    static ULONG WINAPI IncThread(PVOID p)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<Task*>(p)->Inc(), 0;
    }

    void Inc()
    {
        if (WaitTaskReady() == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            if (ULONG n = _n)
            {
                HANDLE hObjectToSignal  = _hEvent[1], hObjectToWaitOn  = _hEvent[0];

                for (;;)
                {
                    if (_shared_value) __debugbreak();

                    if (n < 17) DbgPrint("Inc(%u)\n", n);

                    _shared_value++;

                    if (!--n)
                    {
                        SetEvent(hObjectToSignal);
                        break;
                    }

                    if (SignalObjectAndWait(hObjectToSignal, hObjectToWaitOn, INFINITE, FALSE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        End();
    }

    static ULONG WINAPI DecThread(PVOID p)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<Task*>(p)->Dec(), 0;
    }

    void Dec()
    {
        if (WaitTaskReady() == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            if (ULONG n = _n)
            {
                HANDLE hObjectToSignal  = _hEvent[0], hObjectToWaitOn  = _hEvent[1];

                if (WaitForSingleObject(hObjectToWaitOn, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    for (;;)
                    {
                        --_shared_value;

                        if (_shared_value) __debugbreak();

                        if (n < 17) DbgPrint("Dec(%u)\n", n);

                        if (!--n)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        if (SignalObjectAndWait(hObjectToSignal, hObjectToWaitOn, INFINITE, FALSE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        End();
    }

    ULONG Create()
    {
        ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(_hEvent);
        do 
        {
            if (HANDLE hEvent = CreateEventW(0, n > 2, 0, 0)) _hEvent[--n] = hEvent; 
            else return GetLastError();
        } while (n);

        return NOERROR;
    }

    ULONG Start()
    {
        static PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE aa[] = { IncThread, DecThread };

        ULONG n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(aa);

        do 
        {
            Begin();
            if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, aa[--n], this, 0, 0))
            {
                CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
            else
            {
                n = GetLastError();
                End();
                return n;
            }
        } while (n);

        return NOERROR;
    }

    ULONG Start(ULONG n)
    {
        _iTasks = 1;

        ULONG dwError = Start();

        _n = dwError ? 0 : n;

        SetTaskReady();

        End();

        return dwError;
    }
};

void TaskTest(ULONG n)
{
    Task task;
    if (task.Create() == NOERROR)
    {
        task.Start(n);
        task.WaitTaskEnd();
    }
}
```

note, that no any sense declare local variable (which will be accessed only from single thread and not accessed by any interrupts, etc) as *volatile*

also when we write code, like:

```
// thread #1
write_shared_data();
SetEvent(hEvent);

// thread #2
WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
read_shared_data();
```

inside SetEvent(hEvent); was atomic write to event state with release semantic (really stronger of course) and inside wait for event function - atomic read it state with more than acquire semantic. as result all what thread #1 write to memory before SetEvent - will be visible to thread #2 after Wait for event (if wait finished as result of call Set from thread #1)

Answer (score 3):

A mutex is not the right tool to synchronize two threads, it is there to protect a resource. You do have a resource `j` which is protected by your mutex, however the sequence of which thread gets the lock is undefined, so you can have the case where `dec` gets called several times before `inc` has the chance to run.

If you want to synchronize the order of the threads you will have to use another synchronization primitive, for example a semaphore. You could, for example, increment the semaphore in `inc` and decrement it in `dec`. This would be the classic producer - consumer relationship where the producer will be stalled when the semaphore reaches its maximum value and the consumer will wait for items to consume.

Sorry, no WinAPI C++98 solution from me because that would be silly, but I hope I pointed you to the right direction.

Comment: Sorry but is not Mutex the same that a BinarySemaphore?

Comment: @emanuelclur No, it is usually undefined behavior or not allowed for a mutex to be unlocked by another thread then the one that locked it. A binary semaphore is built for exactly that.

Comment: *no WinAPI C++98 solution from me because that would be silly* i be not agree with this - winapi (if we not care about portability) - much more power and easy for use for such tasks. (in compare c++ libraries, which is very poor and not efficient here). but when we use winapi for solution - no any different between c++98 or say c++20.

Comment: @RbMm There are many reasons why I think insisting using naked WinAPI or C++98 nowadays is silly, but the main reason for this answer is that the problem did not have to do anything with the implementation but the understanding of the thread synchronization primitives, and I believe I have answered that question on this higher level. Thus, I think the OP is capable of writing his implementation, and it would be not only silly to type out some code for WinAPI C++98, which I disagree with using and have not used for a long time, but also a wrong sign to other readers who think it would be ok.

Comment: my think that the c ++ libraries facilities are very poor and limited compared to winapi

Comment: @RbMm No, they are pretty good. Both the C++13 `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` compile down to a few WinAPI calls on Windows. But they have the benefit of being platform independent.

Comment: I have a different opinion. C++ std lib features are very poor and inefficient compared to what we can do with winapi (or other native os calls) help. this is the price for platform independent